# Hide prices and disable checkout for guests

Tags: magento, checkout

Is there any extension that allows to hide product prices and disable checkout for not logged in users?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to allow non logged in users the ability to still browse the catalog...  correct??  Just not see prices and/or checkout.  I only ask because blocking all non-logged users is easy.

Comment: Exactly. Non-logged users should browse catalog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instructions on how to modify yourself:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/22673/

Look for the instructions posted by szotyi about halfway down the post.  He does a nice job of walking you through the process.

Or, one you can buy:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bolasevich/extension/2096/hide-product-price-for-non-registered-users

Finally, one that is even more expensive:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Cart2Quote/extension/5905/not2order_hide_price_disable_ordering

Comment: The first link is dead

Comment: @RThomas Maybe all the 3 links are now obsolete?

Answer (score 2):

Our B2B module also supports this feature and some more: https://github.com/sitewards/B2BProfessional

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this http://www.magikcommerce.com/magento-hide-price-extension Magento extension which hides the product prices, enables call for price functionality and even let you configure various other options.