# Magento: How to block the catalog to guest users?

Tags: magento

I found a question about how to block guests from checking out on Magento 
[Hide prices and disable checkout for guests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299366/hide-prices-and-disable-checkout-for-guests)

I'm faily new to Magento and wanted to ask you how do you block all non-registered users from seen the catalog?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to your site main template:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):?>
//code for logged in members
<?php else:?>
//code for guests
<?php endif;?>
```